# Creating Animations on the web in js, Tween, Spring, user interaction, interruptible and mixing it all in a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, animation, translate, tween

Back story.

I am a web developer and i can pretty much do anything on the web. When i first started doing some programming it was in flash actionscript 3, and i was 14 and now i am 29 and still i haven't figure out this one thing. I have decided i am going to get to the bottom of it finally.

Goals.

To make the problem tangible.

Implement a carousel that can be swiped, autoplay, move with prev and next button, any of these animation should be interruptible and have velocity associated with it, except the mouse/finger tracking. I want it to feel natural, i want the elements moving to feel like they have weight and they are sliding into place. They need to feel real like they can be touched.
The animation needs to be additive, as i change directions and interact with it, it needs to be like how a human would expect it to be. Like they are sliding a piece of plastic on a smooth surface. It needs to snap into place when it is completed.

Now i know stack over flow it's all about show your work. I have done so many times and it all comes down to a mess. So a truce, please give comments and directions and i will update the question with the current progress and roadblocks. I will make and then i will keep it updated.

My Starting point

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-darkness-3hmub

Concepts.

So here are things i think i need to be thinking about.
I believe there are really two types of animations i need to account for.

Tweens and Spring or animations with velocity (i don't know what i am doing).

```js
interface {
   type:"tween"|"velocity";
   velocity:number; //unit per/second??? pixel
   duration?:number;
   from:number;
   to:number;
   start_time:number;
   easing:(progress:number)=>number
}
```

Thought Process.

I think i need the animations to stack. So i need to know when the animation started and what type it is. I need to know if the new animation should completely remove all previous ones or if it should stack on top of it.

For example i could have stacks of all sorts of animations but if a use touches it then it needs to remove them.

I think i need the start time to do things such as easing functions. I want it to have weight and feel like it has inertia.

Contributing.
You may not be able to answer, but suggest, brain storm. I want to put this to bed!

I am committed!! Contribute however you can and i will do the work!!!

Comment: I have made great progress. i am still solving some things i need to solve. I will simplify it as soon as i can and get it in here. Just so i can give a small update. You will need to use bezier curve if you want smooth transitions at any point that a user reverses something. I use the current velocity to project my end point of the animation (using easing functions) then i transfer this to a bezier curve to make the animation smooth, i will display code when it's in a decent form to explain.
https://javascript.info/bezier-curve, This is what i use as the second easing function going back.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be accomplished using https://github.com/react-voodoo/react-voodoo ( beta, incomplete css interpolation support ),

Or directly using https://github.com/react-voodoo/tween-axis

tween-axis allow merging any numeric tween on a "tween-axis".

Once instantiated, we can use a classic goto function to update numeric props on a specified context object.

Even more, multiple tween-axis instance can update the same props.

```
let axis    = new TweenAxis(
    [
        {
            from    : 0,
            duration: 100,
            target  : "myTargetId",
            easeFn:"easePolyOut", // https://github.com/d3/d3-ease or function
            apply   : {
                value: 200
            }
        },
        {
            from    : 0,
            duration: 100,
            target  : "myTargetId",
            apply   : {
                value: -100
            }
        }
    ]
),

   context = {
        myTargetId: {
            value: 0
        }
    };

console.log(axis.go(.5, context));
//{ myTargetId: { value: 50 } }
console.log(axis.go(.25, context));
//{ myTargetId: { value: 25 } }
console.log(axis.go(.75, context));
//{ myTargetId: { value: 75 } }
```